# I am facing a problem while I am creating react web while writing dom and route switch they are sending this error to me

Tags: reactjs

I tried to check the version and it is compatible to React. The problem is when I am writing the code to have a navbar, then an error occurred telling me about the router and route. I asked my friend then I wrote an element instead of component.

Comment: Sorry, no one here can address issues in code we can't see regarding errors we don't know. Please [edit] to include the complete error message(s) and any accompanying error stacktrace(s), a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with, and any additional debugging details and information you have. Take the [tour] and review [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) for additional tips to improve the quality of your post to make it on-topic for Stackoverflow.